# how to add text instead of image jquery slideshow?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the query slideshow created by Matt Hinchliffe (http://i-like-robots.github.com/jQuery-Slideshow/)
I really like the simplicity and how fast this slideshow is. To get to my question, on my website (http://www.vanessenstudio.com)

I want this section:

```
    <section id="introduction">
    <div id="example">
    <div class="slideshow" data-transition="scroll" data-loop="true" data-skip="true" data-pagination="false">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="images/facephoto.jpg" width="960" height="400" /></li>
        <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="images/facephoto1.jpg" width="960" height="400" /></li>
        <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="images/facephoto2.jpg" width="960" height="400" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

to have a slide with text with a fixed width and height of 960 by 400. I know I can create a file in Illustrator and save it as an image but I was wondering if it is possible. I replaced ing alt= after li class by  and sure enough text appears. Unfortunately it doesn't appear in the fixed width and height.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply replace the image width some text or any other HTML content and set the width and height of the `<li>`s accordingly to your image size.

Comment: thanks, I got some interesting results like that but unfortunately not to my liking. Instead I now used the cycle jquery. Works like a champ. 

Thanks for your time though!